# Unable to pass Headers parameter in reactjs by using Fetch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, header, fetch

Stuck in unable to pass `headers` parameter in `fetch` call, I tried many different codes snippets by using Stackoverflow as well as Postman code too.

Currently here's the code Snippet for calling GET request by using Fetch method in reactjs

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("mode", "no-cors");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer oauth 2 token");


var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("api url", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Hi everyone,
I'm calling simple calling GET api by using Fetch function, but request Header is unable to pass in the request. But the same request I'm calling from PostMan it's working.
Any idea where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It lloks ok to me, what's your network logs in browser.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov do we need to do this as Headers object will take care of that

Comment: Authorization failed : Unexpected end of input 

This is log due to headers not passing in request

Comment: @Yevgen I tried also but still it;s not working Object.fromEntries(myheaders.entries())